# Downloading Minecraft (Java Edition) on Windows 11

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows

I have tried downloading Minecraft Java Edition on my Windows 11 computer for a bit and it keeps saying "Looks like something went wrong" and bellow that says "We weren't able to install the app (0x80070057)". What should I do? Is there a certain version I need to download?

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per Timmy Jim's comment.

Comment: I do wonder if the same solutions apply to Windows 11, but it indeed seems a duplicate so far.

Answer (score 1):

The new launcher is known to have issues for many players on Windows 11. You should try downloading and installing the Windows 7/8 launcher, which is the launcher that was previously used on Windows 10. Download it [here](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download) and select Windows 7/8.

To get rid of the message about upgrading the launcher, right click the shortcut for the game and change compatibility to Windows 8 on the compatibility tab.